# Dynamically add columns to entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, database-schema, event-listener

I`m working on my own Extension that will include a annotation.

I want to extend my entities by using the annotation. The entities should extended by some extra fields. I do that by listening the metaclassloaded Event.

But doctrine throws an exception because the entities don't have the properties. Is it possible to add them programmatically?

Comment: What do you mean your own extension

Comment: I Work on a custom Extension that i want to publish